# Periodically "Nested/Concurrent transactions aren't supported." error

Tags: c#, npgsql

Customer periodically has "Nested/Concurrent transactions aren't supported." error. Not repeatable on my side, but trying to understand how it could happen. It only happen in following method:

```
public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(CommandType type, string query, params NpgsqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            NpgsqlCommand command = PrepareCommand(type, query, parameters);

            // Use transaction for functions with refcursors. This is necessary to prevent cursors 
            // returned by refcursor function from closing after the implicity transaction is finished 
            // (just after we do the function call).
            NpgsqlTransaction t = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
                System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();

                // Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
                da.Fill(ds);
                t.Commit();

                // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
                command.Parameters.Clear();

                return ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Commit all transactions so connection can be used again (Npgsql does not allow nested transactions)
                t.Rollback();
                // Log error and problem query
                LogError(e);
                // Throw same exception to a higher level for correct handling
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

In case of error I always trying to Rollback to avoid nested transactions, however it happens periodically on some installation. Is it Npgsql problem or something in implementation? How could this happen? Is this connected with connection Pool or something if 2 processes simultaneously runs this method from different classes, apps?

Call stack:

> 2013-10-08
>   13:00:27.6038|Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLogger.WriteInternal|Info|Job
>   DEFAULT.SQLServerSyncScheduledJob threw a JobExecutionException:
>   |System.InvalidOperationException: Nested/Concurrent transactions
>   aren't supported.    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel level)    at
>   Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.BeginTransaction()    at
>   DbFramework.PgDataAccess.ExecuteDataTable(CommandType type, String
>   query, NpgsqlParameter[] parameters)

Comment: Don't know anything about Npgsql, but from the error message, I suspect it is caused if BeginTransaction is called when the sqlconnection is already in the middle of a transaction. This can come about if a transaction is never finished (eg an exception is thrown and not caught, or caught and rollback is not called). Your method above looks ok, but perhaps there is another routine that isn't. But this can also happen if your app is sharing the same SqlConnection between threads. If one thread attempts to create a transaction while another is in the middle of a transaction you get the error.

Comment: _>But this can also happen if your app is sharing the same SqlConnection between threads._<br>

Correct. This is it. I thought connection is different for each thread, but problem was in Castle Windsor container implementation which initialized only single instance for all threads. Fixed initialization code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324033/how-to-register-separate-instance-of-a-class-using-windsor-container