# How to register separate instance of a class using Windsor Container

Tags: c#, servicestack, castle-windsor

Not very familiar with Windsor Container, modifying code written by other person. We have code which initializes all objects in WindsorContainer which has PgDataAccess (own class) data type property

```
public PgDataAccess da { get; set; }
```

Code is the following:

```
    _windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<PgDataAccess>().UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
        {
            var dataAccess = new PgDataAccess();
            dataAccess.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            return dataAccess;
        }));
```

According to some errors seems we had same PgDataAccess class instance is used for all the objects in this container. How to modify this initialization to register separate PgDataAccess class instance in every container's object? Something with following meaning:

```
foreach(component in _windsorContainer.Components.<PgDataAccess>())
{
    var dataAccess = new PgDataAccess();
    dataAccess.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    component.da = dataAccess;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code lifestyle of PgDataAccess is singleton, since "Singleton is the default lifestyle, which will be used if you don't specify anyone explicitly"

So, your code is similar to

```
_windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<PgDataAccess>()
    .LifestyleSingleton()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
    {
        var dataAccess = new PgDataAccess();
        dataAccess.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        return dataAccess;
    }));
```

If you want to have new instance of PgDataAccess for each component that depends on it, you should register it as transient.

```
_windsorContainer.Register(Component.For<PgDataAccess>()
    .LifestyleTransient()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
    {
        var dataAccess = new PgDataAccess();
        dataAccess.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        return dataAccess;
    }));
```

You can read more information about lifestyles [here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ilya. Will Read Castle Windsor documentation. Another quick question here, please: how to iterate through all these elements in container to check if object instances are different by Object.ReferenceEquals() for example?

Comment: You can:
1st invoke container.Resolve<PgDataAccess>() several times and check if instances are not equal.
2nd invoke container.Resolve<YourType>() several times and check if properties "da" on instances of YourType refer to different instances of PgDataAccess.

Comment: Thanks, Ilya, for the reference.